# Where min, max and sum are defined in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I'm wondering where sum(), min(), and max() are defined in python?
for example performing this operation:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
min(a)
```

if I looking for into methods of a list min is not there:

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

Comment: It's not a method of list. It's a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Comment: Methods of list won't include `min` because `min` is not a method. `min` is a builtin function. It also doesn't need anything from list other than being iterable. It needs something more from elements of that iterable, tho - they need to be comparable to each other. (If you can do `for elem in something` then it's iterable. If you can do elem1<elem2, then elem1 and elem2 are comparable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html):

> The Python interpreter has a number of functions and types built into it that are always available. They are listed here in alphabetical order.
>
> **Built-in Functions**
>
> ...
>
> **M**
> `map()`
> `max()`
> `memoryview()`
> `min()`
>
> ...

If they were methods on `list`, you would call them as `a.min()` and `a.max()` instead.

The reason that these functions are global, and not methods, is that they are more universal: they work on any iterable. For example, you can also call `min(x for x in a if x%2 == 0)`, where you're passing it a generator instead.

Answer (score 0):

The sum function is not a method of the list object, like you show there, but a global function. 
It is built into python. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?msclkid=c061f6fbc53b11ec9ef2424170aeda56#sum

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).